# Body-size won't get 100%?

Tags: html, css

I got a Website here: [Website](http://pixeld.bplaced.net/Workbench/)
My Problem is, that the Body (witch I want to make to opacity 0 later) isn't over the whole site? It just stops at after the "Block"-Section in the middle.
When I remove the background-color in the html-part, the Body gets Fullscreen again.
But I need the background-color for another reason. (I don't want to change this).

I hope you can see/edit the source-code with your browser.

I want it this way:
http://postimg.org/image/j2ec1sl9z/

**SOLUTION!!!**
I cant answer my own question right now, so i have to do it this way:

So, my Solution I found is:

I set the height automatic onload with javascript.

```
var wheight = $(window).height();
$("body").css("height", wheight);
```

Not the best Solution, but it works!

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Are you referring to how the `<body>` appears to start half way down the page (where the `section#block` is)?

Comment: you just need a full body background - http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Regarding your edit, why not set the body height to `100%` with CSS?

Comment: Setting it to 100% didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the body's default style which has some margin and padding depending on the browser. So you just need to make sure body doesn't have any margin or padding. So  try this.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**Update**:  Add background image on `html` Set `background-size:cover`

```
html{
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(Blurred.jpg);
}
```

and remove it from your existing section ie. `body` style otherwise it will display twice.

OR Just remove this line at `line 5` in `style.css`

```
html {
 background-color: #EDEDED;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will fill the site on left and right, but I also need it verticaly, any Ideas?

Comment: @DominikSeemayr what do you mean by `vertically`. Should your image start from the top, which left the space at the bottom because your image doesn't have much  height? is it so? or do you want to have full page background?

Comment: Want the full-page background. (Updated Question)

Comment: I want it in the Body-Tag, because I want to set the body-opacity to 0 with an transition later by javascript. Then i need a background-color in html. I just want the Body-Tag to be full-screen.

Comment: I don't want to remove the background-color, because I need it for another thing. I found a solution by myself right now, i updated the question!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get around is to remove all the browser's default margins and padding

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 body: 0;
}
```

This way, all the margins will be removed, and your body tag will fill the space!

Example:

In your website, you can see that the user's browser is giving this margin on its own

[image]

The problem is having a caption of `user agent stylesheet` which means that this issue is being created by the user's browser. The margin being added is `8px`.

And now, when you will set `margin: 0` it will update the user's stylesheet and the style that you will provide will be used. Which is `0`.

Now the second error with the image is that `id="Block` is being provided with `margin-top: 183.5px;` remove it or replace it with `margin: 0;` That will do :)

To fill the space for the body, you can use the `min-width` and `min-height` to make sure the body tag is always filled.

Then use an image which would fill the whole space of the browser screen.

Comment: While at it, should go ahead and make it `html, body {`

Comment: Thanks, that will fill the site on left and right, but I also need it verticaly, any Ideas?

Comment: `html, body {` should work, but there was no HTML being applied any style :) So I didn't bother confusing the asker :)

Comment: There might be some other issues, your image might be transparent from the top!

Comment: Check the edit..I have updated the answer for the image too :) There was a margin..

Comment: I want to have the Block in the middle of the page, that's the reason I want it to have "margin-top: middle of your page(made the calculation with javascript). So I don't want to change the margin of Block..

Comment: Then I am sorry your image won't be placed there! It will be placed here.. Because of the margin :)

Comment: Changed the margin to padding, now it's filled TILL the Block.
Under the Block the picture ends. Any Ideas how to stretch the body to the bottom?

Comment: To stretch the body tag, use `min-width` this will make sure that body should have this width as minimum!

Answer (score 0):

You  may have issues with ["margin collapse"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

> "...adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding, or border areas, or
>   clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to
>   one another or nested) combine to form a single margin."

The `margin-top` of your child element `section#block` is also pushing down its parent `<body>`.
Try changing it to `padding-top`, instead:

```
$(ID).css("padding-top", half + "px");
```

I also suggest giving `<html>` and `<body>` some height and removing any default margins/padding:

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this filled the background to the upper site! Now I need it to bring it to the bottom!

Comment: Edited my answer. Check the stuff about `height:100%`.

Comment: It's working for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGK8G/ What do you see going wrong?

Comment: Really don't know why it didn't work for me. I solved it by setting the height of the body automatic by javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would provide some type of alternative to resetting the body margins. I ran into the same issue with one of my sites as well. The way I got around it without resetting margins is to set the height to 100%.

`<body onload="centerVertical('Block')" id="body" style="height:100%">`

and

`<html style="height:100%">`.

I would post a picture of the edits within your site, but I need 10 rep to post images.

```
function cry(){for(1=1){return tears;}}
```

Comment: Setting `height` won't affect the margins. With `height:100%` and some default margins set, there will always be a vertical scrollbar because `100% + margin > 100%`. Illustrated here: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ELg/) vs [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ELg/1/).

Comment: I understand. I was trying to solve the issue without effecting margins (as with my site, the margins were important). The height fix I proposed pulled the background image vertically to the entire page, top and bottom, without effecting the margins. That's what I did with mine and his sites and they both worked without messing with the margins. I agree though, if margins are not in issue, by all means, mess away!

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood you. But how did you get your margins not to increase the calculated height of `<body>`? Generally, `height:100%` plus margins will make a vertical scrollbar appear. Are you using IE (quirks mode) or CSS `box-sizing` to adjust the box model?

Comment: Nada and nothing of the sort. Sorry, I'm terrible at explaining (which is why I'm not a teacher :P). Here, coding might help. `<html style="height:100%">` which wraps around the body, but the body is set to margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:50px;. This does not produce a scrollbar, but extends the background:cover to the entirety of the page. I have a sticky nav bar at the top, however, so the margins of  the entire HTML can't be messed with or the nav bar goes bat-crap-crazy.

Comment: Oh gotcha! Height on `html` and margin on `body`. Thanks for explaining it for me.